# What makes a good network planner software on Linux?

Tags: networking, software-rec

I need to design a VoIP network topology for a customer and I need a software that can do as that famous Windows one, don't remember the name.

Comment: You mean drawing a scheme?

Comment: Yeah. There is an app on Windows that let you make network topology maps with icons and different kind of connectors, etc . It's called visio I think. Is there any opensource alternative ?

Comment: Try www.gliffy.com.

Comment: Dia is useful for drawing diagrams. There are built in icons for all kind of network devices.

Answer (score 3):

Options that comes into my mind as alternatives to Microsoft Visio:

- Gliffy: http://www.gliffy.com/uses/network-diagram-software/
- Dia: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Download
- Cade: http://www.weresc.com/cade.php
- Diagram Designer: http://d16912502.u227.surftown.dk/DiagramDesigner/Templates/
- yEd: http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_gallery.html

Some of them will require to download extra Template objects, that have the network topology symbols.

If you want something to emulate your network behavior and planning, CORE could be a solution: http://www.nrl.navy.mil/itd/ncs/products/core